# Kingfisher load image from url and set corner radius

Tags: ios, uiimageview, kingfisher

I layout imageView with SnapKit and load image from url by Kingfisher, I also want to set corner radius by Kingfisher (use `RoundCornerImageProcessor`), if I set targetSize, picture is distorted, if not set, just corner radius, i can't get the results I want.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can set image easily like this for kingFisher:

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image:UIImageView!
    let rawstring = "https://apis.baytelhekma.com/zinzo/public/storage/products/November2020/eUWwRjNCYCdHUjGIQiJk.png"
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let url = URL(string: rawstring)
            image.kf.setImage(with: url)
            
           
        }
   

}
```

Then you can make corner radius by adding this to your project:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            let color = UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
            return color
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }
    
}
```

after that all you need to do is this in your `ViewController`:

```
image.cornerRadius = 15 // you can set it with the number fits your app
```